# How to convert SimpleFormController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Currently I'm using `SimpleFormController` but there's I'm getting `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'name' available as request attribute`

So here is my code but I don't know how to convert it

```
public LoginController() {
        setCommandClass(Customer.class);
        setCommandName("name");
        setSuccessView("userAccount");
        setFormView("loginView");
    }
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {
        Customer name = (Customer) command;
        ApplicationContext ac = new
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ICHDApp/Spring-Config.xml");
        Account act = (Account) ac.getBean("AccountBean");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("helloMessage", loginService.sayHello(name.getUserName()));
        String str = ("Account Number:"+act.getAccountNumber());
        mv.addObject("accountNumber", str);
        String str1 = ("Account Balance ($):"+act.getBalance());
        mv.addObject("accountBalance", str1);
        mv;
    }
```

So what changes will be in entire code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see with the code is that you do not pass any object to "name"

Comment: Guju `setCommandName("name");` and binded with `<spring:nestedpath name="name">` but getting error  mentioned above.

Comment: I may have been unclear, excuse me for that. What I meant was, have you tried setting mv.addObject("name", theNameYouWantToSend); ?

Comment: So since I found on stack overflow that `@Controller` annotation recommended to them who facing this problem.

Comment: Yes it resolved my problem but doesn't map to desire page as if userAccount. That entire tutorial is incomplete and that's why it's been problematic.